# Message not added to Azurite Queue from Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-queues, azure-storage-explorer

Following the documentation below I trying to create an azure function which adds a message to a queue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-add-output-binding-storage-queue-vs?tabs=in-process#add-an-output-binding

The code gets triggered and executes with out an error, but I could not see any message in the Azure Storage Explorer Queue.

I added Azurite Storage account to my local Storage Explorer. But the queue does not get created and the message is not getting added.

AzureWebJobsStorage is set to "UseDevelopmentStorage=true".

How do I test this locally in the storage explorer? What are the steps and what all do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue by following steps:

1. Created Azure Functions (Stack: .Net Core 3.1 - Http Trigger) in Visual Studio.
2. Installed this package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage` through Nuget Package Solution to the Project.
3. Added the Output Queue binding to the Task static method like:

`public static async Task<IActionResult> Run( [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, [Queue("outqueue"), StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")] ICollector<string> msg, ILogger log)`

Added the code which writes the passed parameter in the function URL to the output queue (before parsing the response message code):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
    // Add a message to the output collection.
    msg.Add(string.Format("Name passed to the function: {0}", name));
    }
```

Now the full code looks is:

[image]

**local.settings.json**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

5. Run the function locally and copy the function URL that comes in the console to the browser along with parameters like:
   `http://localhost:7071/api/Function1?name=HariKrishna`
   Then it should be displayed in the browser as `Hello, HariKrishna. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.`
6. Go to the ***Storage Explorer*** >  Expand ***Queues*** and refresh it (*right-click on queues and click refresh*) to see the queue created by functions runtime while a function is running and refresh the **output queue** also to see the messages as you can the console output, browser output and Queue messages in below screenshot:

[image]

[image]